# Not getting indexPath for tapping UISwitch in a UITableViewCell

Tags: ios, ios5, uitableview, uiswitch

I added a UISwitch in a UITableViewCell, the table contents are dynamics, which means that there may be many UISwitches in a tableview, I need to get the UISwitch state for every UITableViewCell, but not getting the `indexPath` in `accessoryButtonTappedForRowWithIndexPath` method.

my code is:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    LocationCell *cell = (LocationCell *)[tableView 
                                          dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"LocationCell"];

    UISwitch *useLocationSwitch = [[UISwitch alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];
    [cell addSubview:useLocationSwitch];
    cell.accessoryView = useLocationSwitch;

    [useLocationSwitch addTarget: self
               action: @selector(accessoryButtonTapped:withEvent:)
     forControlEvents: UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

    return cell;
}

- (void) accessoryButtonTapped: (UIControl *) button withEvent: (UIEvent *) event
{
    NSIndexPath * indexPath = [showLocationTableView indexPathForRowAtPoint: [[[event touchesForView: button] anyObject] locationInView: showLocationTableView]];
    if ( indexPath == nil )
        return;

    [showLocationTableView.delegate tableView: showLocationTableView accessoryButtonTappedForRowWithIndexPath: indexPath];
}

-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView accessoryButtonTappedForRowWithIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    NSLog(@"index path: %@", indexPath.row);
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The control event should be `UIControlEventValueChanged`.

Not `UIControlEventTouchUpInside`. Change that and try again.

So the action setting statement should be as follows:

```
[useLocationSwitch addTarget: self
                      action: @selector(accessoryButtonTapped:withEvent:)
            forControlEvents: UIControlEventValueChanged];
```

**Edit:**

```
- (void) accessoryButtonTapped: (UIControl *) button withEvent: (UIEvent *) event
{
    UISwitch *switch1 = (UISwitch *)button;
    UITableViewCell *cell = (UITableViewCell *)switch1.superview;
    NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForCell:cell];

    //NSIndexPath * indexPath = [showLocationTableView indexPathForRowAtPoint: [[[event touchesForView: button] anyObject] locationInView: showLocationTableView]];
    if ( indexPath == nil )
        return;

    [showLocationTableView.delegate tableView: showLocationTableView accessoryButtonTappedForRowWithIndexPath: indexPath];
}
```

Comment: still not getting index value

Comment: I have updated my answer. Its not tested. I'll test it soon (few mins) once I get into the mac machine.

Comment: Yes, it is tested and should give expected value.

Comment: Use this in iOS 7     CGPoint switchPositionPoint = [sender convertPoint:CGPointZero toView:[self tableView]];
    NSIndexPath *indexPath = [[self tableView] indexPathForRowAtPoint:switchPositionPoint];